# How to remove DIV from asp.net table formatting of memo field

Tags: asp.net

I am binding a msaccess db to an asp.net table. For memo field, text have div tag around them in the html table cell that appears literaly for end user.

Is there an option to avoid these div ?

Source code for aspx:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Source for .cs:

```
        myDB = "MyDB";
        myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|" + myDB + ".accdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;";
        OleDbConnection myDataCon = new OleDbConnection(myConString);

        myDataCon.Open();


        OleDbCommand dbCom = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Test", myDataCon);
        OleDbDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = dataReader;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        dataReader.Close();
        myDataCon.Close();
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the table?

Comment: Look in to using TemplateField column so you can have more control over the output.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228046(v=vs.100).aspx